# Unload loaded dlls of external process

Tags: c#, winapi, visual-c++

Does somebody know how to unload a dll or any other type of module loaded by an external process?

I tried to do `GetModuleHandle` and then `FreeLibrary` with no result...

Thank you for all your replies

Thank you for all your replies. I found an interesting msdn article here :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/managed-create-remote-thread.aspx

The problem is that when i try to do a OpenProcess the external process crashes.

What are the minimum process access rights to unload a module from it ?

Here is what i am trying to do in c# :
[code]
protected const int PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | SYNCHRONIZE | 0xFFF);
protected const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
protected const int SYNCHRONIZE = 0x100000;

```
    public static bool UnloadRemoteModule(FileEntry le)
    {
        try
        {
            Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(le.ProcessID);

            if (process == null) return false;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(le.File);

            UnloadModuleThreadProc umproc = new UnloadModuleThreadProc(UnloadModule);
            IntPtr fpProc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(umproc);               

            SafeProcessHandle processHandle = null;

            IntPtr currentProcess = NativeMethods.GetCurrentProcess();
            int processId = le.ProcessID;
            bool remote = (processId != NativeMethods.GetProcessId(currentProcess));

            try
            {
                if (remote)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("OPENING PROCESS !");
                    processHandle = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, true, processId);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    uint dwThreadId;

                    if (processHandle.DangerousGetHandle() == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("COULD NOT OPEN HANDLE !");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Create a thread in the first process.
                        IntPtr hThread = CreateRemoteThread(
                            processHandle.DangerousGetHandle(),
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            0,
                            fpProc, IntPtr.Zero,
                            0,
                            out dwThreadId);

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

                        WaitForThreadToExit(hThread);
                    }

                }
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (remote)
                {                        
                    if (processHandle != null)
                    {
                        processHandle.Close();
                    }                       
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Module.ShowError(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public delegate int UnloadModuleThreadProc(IntPtr sb_module_name);

    static int UnloadModule(IntPtr sb_module_name2)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\a\logerr.txt"))
        {
            sw.AutoFlush = true;
            sw.WriteLine("In Unload Module");

            StringBuilder sb_module_name =new StringBuilder(@"C:\Windows\System32\MyDll.dll");

            IntPtr mh = DetectOpenFiles.GetModuleHandle(sb_module_name.ToString());

            sw.WriteLine("LAST ERROR="+Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());

            sw.WriteLine("POINTER="+mh.ToInt32());

            if (mh != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return (FreeLibrary(mh) ? 1 : 0);
            }

            sw.WriteLine("LAST ERROR 2 =" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
            sw.WriteLine("EXIT " + mh.ToInt32());
        }

        return 0;
    }[/code]
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. Modules are loaded into a process by that process, so how would you unload a module loaded by another process into that other process? In other words, what other processes are doing is none of your process's business.

Comment: A tip: don't end your question with anything that looks like "can i has the codez plz".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it, but honestly I must ask why? You're most likely going to screw things up beyond what you realize. Seriously, there's nothing that can go right if you do this. Don't read the rest of this post, close your browser, do some meditation, and figure out what you're doing wrong that made you ask this question.

**HERE BE DRAGONS**

That said, it can be done, and rather easily too.

All you have to do is use [`CreateRemoteThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), pass a handle to the process you want to force unload in, and a function pointer to a function that calls `GetModuleHandle` and `FreeLibrary`. Easy as pie.

Sample code (untested, written in vi, and not to be used no matter what):

```
DWORD WINAPI UnloadNamedModule(void *)
{
    //If you value your life, don't use this code
    LPCTSTR moduleName = _T("MYMODULE.DLL");
    HMODULE module = GetModuleHandle(moduleName);

    if (module != NULL)
    {
        UnloadModule(hModule);
        //All hell breaks loose. Not even this comment will be reached.
        //On your own head be it. Don't say I didn't warn you.
    }
}

//Warning: this function should never be run!
void UnloadRemoteModule(HANDLE hProcess)
{
    CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, UnloadNamedModule, NULL, 0);
}
```

Comment: This is a *great* answer, both for its technical validity and the copious reiterations of warnings.

Comment: I must say it's a very clever way around the problem. I hope the warnings will be heeded. I am only allowed 1 upvote otherwise I would have given more :)

Comment: Recursion for the win :) ... +1 ... of course you forgot that this function itself would have to be loaded into the remote process first and only then can the `CreateRemoteProcess` succeed. But let us not tell anyone ;)

Comment: You're right, of course! (It's 6am and I should go to sleep. My original answer passed a char pointer to the UnloadModule function. Talk about silly!)

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. I found an interesting msdn article here :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/09/28/managed-create-remote-thread.aspx

Answer (score 1):

*You cannot force an external process to unload it's modules. You would need to run that code from inside the external process.* The best you can hope for is to kill the process that owns the external DLL. It would be extremely dangerous if you could unload a dll from an external process, the code could be running at the time that you pull it out of RAM.

If you are looking to replace the DLL, the best you can do is to rename the DLL and save the new one. That way, the DLL will get use the next time the external process loads it.

***Correction to italics above: You can do it but you are asking for big trouble if you do. I still think the best approach is to do what I listed above, rename the DLL and put the new one in it's place for the next time the external process starts. It's a far safer approach if you would like to replace a DLL.***

Comment: Yes you can, but no you shouldn't. See my answer.

Comment: Ok, see what you are doing. Ouch, that is dangerous.

Comment: :) Indeed. Hence my new disclaimers!

Comment: Hopefully the OP listens to it :)

Comment: I will take a look for you. My concern is not about whether it can or can't be done. If you look at Mahmoud's post, it most certainly can be done. The risks are just huge in doing so. If you have control over the external application that hosts the DLL then you should be able to create some sort of API to get the application to remove the library from memory. If not, then you have no idea what the application is doing at the time you inject the new thread. It could be running code from that library at the time you yank it out of ram. That's the big danger with this.

Comment: Is the process you are trying to open running as a Windows Service?